# How does one pronounce monarchie?

Tags: prononciation

How does one pronounce the French word monarchie? Is the ch as in French chaise or as in English psychic?

Comment: I've flagged this as off-topic, since this read to me as a general reference question that can be easily solved by looking up a dictionary that gives pronunciation rules, such as [this one](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monarchie) -- see [this](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/20/4082) for some idea of what I'm getting at.

Comment: @Maroon:  Not everyone can read IPA and the wiktionary doesn't have the audio for the French *monarchie*, but you can [listen to it find on forvo](http://fr.forvo.com/word/monarchie/#fr) and maybe other places. Anyway, I agree this question can be "answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information".

Comment: This question can be answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information.

Answer (score 0):

All -archie are pronounced like "she".